# how to pass class object as variable as constructor parameter in another class?

Tags: java

I have one class called Fullname having variables fname,mname and lname.
Then another class Participant having variable name of type Fullname, marks of type int.
In another class I have to create array of Participant of size 5 and have to store information from  user input.

My problem is how to read value for Fullname variable and then pass it as constructor parameter.
while using scanner it is giving error that cannot convert from string to Fullname.

I am not getting correct output for Fullname variable

```
public class Participant {
    fullname name;
    int rollno;
    float marks;

    public Participant(fullname nameFullname, int rollno, float marks) {
        super();
        this.name=new fullname(null, null, null);
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name=" + name + ", rollno=" + rollno + ", marks=" + marks + "";
    }
}

public class Implements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = null, b = null, c = null;
        int rollno = 0;
        float marks = 0;
        Participant part[] = new Participants[5];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        rollno = sc.nextInt();
        marks = sc.nextFloat();
        a = sc.next();
        b = sc.next();
        c = sc.next();

        Fullname name = new Fullname(a, b, c);

        part[1] = new Participant(name, rollno, marks);
        System.out.println(part[1].toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: It is difficult to help you without seeing what YOU tried

Comment: Edit the question to add your code, don't post it in a comment.

Comment: I made few changes in the code still not getting correct output of 'name'.

Answer (score 0):

> sc.next()

is returning a `String` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) and you are trying to assign it to a `Fullname` object. `Fullname` isn't an instance of String so it isn't valid.
If you want to do this assignment you will need to implement a function to handel this for you.

```
part=new participants(name,rollno,marks)
```

Doesn't work because you declared part as an array and you are trying to assign `Participants` to it. (that class should be declared with a capital letter by the way). If you want to assign it, add an index. (for example `part[0] = new participants(name,rollno,marks)`)